# Columns not inline?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create two columns with a shared title above them.

However, whenever I use:

```
.quick-links {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

The text isn't inline in the two columns. Here is what I mean:
https://gyazo.com/9446be53ea0d402c52b84768f13f090d

It might not be blatantly obvious to everyone, but, trust me, it's there and it bugs the hell out of me!

Any ideas on how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<section class="quicklinks">
    <h1>Quicklinks:</h1>
    <div class="quick-links">
        <!-- Client Reviews -->
        <figure class="reviews">
            <img src="images/RatingsTick.png" alt="Ratings Tick Image">
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <p><strong>Reviews</strong></p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <!-- Portfolio -->
        <figure class="portfolio">
            <img src="images/Portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio Image">
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <p><strong>Previous Work</strong></p>

            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.quick-links img {
    height: 7.5em;
    width: 7.5em;
    border-radius: 10em;
}

.quick-links {
    column-count: 2;
}

.quick-links h1 {
    column-span: all;
}
```

Comment: I added a display: inline-block; and for those that don't see it, look how obvious it is now:
https://gyazo.com/a98f706fe3e63a649e6e64b651bcb193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try         `display: flex;` instead of column-count:2

```css
 
.quick-links img {
    height: 7.5em;
    width: 7.5em;
    border-radius: 10em;
}

.quick-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.quick-links h1 {
    column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<section class="quicklinks">
    <h1>Quicklinks:</h1>
    <div class="quick-links">
        <!-- Client Reviews -->
        <figure class="reviews">
            <img src="images/RatingsTick.png" alt="Ratings Tick Image">
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <p><strong>Reviews</strong></p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <!-- Portfolio -->
        <figure class="portfolio">
            <img src="images/Portfolio.png" alt="Portfolio Image">
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <p><strong>Previous Work</strong></p>

            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you. But how would I now get them centered on the page?

Comment: Please check updated answer,Added justify-content:center;

Comment: Ah you added it in!

Comment: Perfect thank you. However, what would I replace column-width with? I was hoping to add some more text later on that would require column-width to be used.

Comment: Where will you add the text, Please update the ques with image and code of what you want then may be ican help you

Comment: I've added the text in and it turns out it looks just fine! Thanks for your help.